# Non-static Thread as arg for static function throws NullPointerException

Tags: java, multithreading, static, arraylist

Im working with a program that should run some jobs in background.
Before application closes, it should wait for the remaining jobs to complete before actually closing, so i've made class with a static array list to store the running threads so I can access all those jobs from a global-scope on my app and get the result i wanted.

```
public class BackgroundWorker extends javax.swing.JDialog {
    private static ArrayList thlist;

    public static void DoThisThingAndDontBotherMe(Thread t) {
        thlist.add(t); // :3
        t.start();
    }

    public static void WaitForJobsToBeDone() {
        for(Object o : thlist.toArray()) {
            if(!((Thread) o).isAlive()) {
                thlist.remove(o);
            }
        }
        if(thlist.isEmpty())
            return;
        for(int i = 0; i < thlist.size(); i++) {
            try {
                ((Thread) thlist.get(i)).join();
            } catch(InterruptedException e) { System.err.println("Crap. A thread failed!! X.x");
        }
    }
}
```

... But when I call this from outer class, like this:

```
BackgroundWorker.DoThisThingAndDontBotherMe(new Thread() {
    System.out.println("HEY, im a creepy thread! But ill soon cause this program to throw a NullPointerExeption. And the lame programmer won't know why >:D");
});
```

The program throws a null pointer exception in the line commented with a ':3' as if the call to new Thread(){} was a null pointer >.>

PS: If i do create a new Thread variable in that manner, without calling my class and then call its start() method, the thread does its job as intended. But I need those threads to be stored in a global-accessible list so I can wait it to finish before I can close my app.
PS 2: The function names above are just representative and are not the names I'm using in my application. I dont use long names for functions and types.

Which of static/non-static rule did I not consider? x.x

Comment: `thlist` not initialized

Comment: Where is `thlist` initialized?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to instantiate `thlist`

```
private static ArrayList thlist = new ArrayList();
```

It is better to use generics here:

```
private static ArrayList<Thread> thlist = new ArrayList<>();
```

(if you use Java 7) or:

```
private static ArrayList<Thread> thlist = new ArrayList<Thread>();
```

if not.

Comment: Tyvm buddy, this answer clarifies perfectly my question.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `BackgroundWorker.DoThisThingAndDontBotherMe(new Thread()....` have you made sure that your `ArrayList thlist;`  has been initialized?

Answer (score 0):

you need to initialize your list:

```
ArrayList myList = new ArrayList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to re-invent an [`ExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html).

You could solve the problem in a more effective and idiomatic way by doing something like (with the shutdown method taken directly from the JavaDoc page):

```
public class BackgroundWorker extends javax.swing.JDialog
{
  private final ExecutorService _executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NUMBER_OF_CONCURRENT_OPERATIONS);

  public void doThisThingAndDontBotherMe(Runnable runnable)
  {
    _executorService.execute(runnable);
  }

  public void waitForJobsToBeDone()
  { 
    _executorService.shutdown();
    try 
    {
      // Wait a while for existing tasks to terminate
      if (!_executorService.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) 
      {
        _executorService.shutdownNow(); // Cancel currently executing tasks
        // Wait a while for tasks to respond to being cancelled
        if (!_executorService.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
          System.err.println("Pool did not terminate");
      }
    } 
    catch (InterruptedException ie) 
    {
      // (Re-)Cancel if current thread also interrupted
      _executorService.shutdownNow();
      // Preserve interrupt status
      Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Clearly this doesn't directly answer the OP's question, but it's reasonably clear what their intention was and I believe this is a far more effective way of solving his problem (not to mention more maintainable for the next person to see his code).  Either way, I've added a concrete example.

Comment: Ive ommited some logics, BackgroundWorker has some non-static instantiable stuff to show progress bars on screen based on static information;

Comment: @Felype I'm not sure why that would stop you using an `ExecutorService`.

Answer (score 0):

YOU forgot to initialize

```
ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
```